# Definitive way of figuring out companies with multiple classes of stocks

Tags: data, market-data, fundamentals, sec

Is there a definitive way of mapping tickers to companies for companies with multiple listed tickers? For example, GOOG and GOOGL are both Google (or now Alphabet), or BRK.A and BRK.B are both Berkshire

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download the company list csvs from [nasdaq.com](http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/company-list.aspx), it has the mapping you need.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you access to CRSP say under WRDS (https://wrds-web.wharton.upenn.edu/wrds/), then you can track a company not by its ticker but by its CUSIP.